# Multiple condition sum with '%_total'

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum, conditional-statements

I am aiming to produce code that generates an independent total check. As per  the below table:

```
 column1   Column2   Column3   value   independent total check
  A         B         c1         10      Null                   
  A         B         c2         11      Null                   
  A         B         C_total    21      21                    
  x         y         z1         10      Null                   
  x         y         z2         20      Null                   
  x         y         z_total    30      30                    

 I am trying to employ a conditional sum, but with no success! What I have at the moment is:

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Temp
select  t2.Column1, t2.Column2, t2.Column3,t2.value,
sum (case when (t2.column3 like '%_Total%' and t2.T_desk not like '%Total%') then t2.Value else Null end) over (partition by t2.Column2)  as "independent_total_check"into #Temp from #sometemptable
```

This does not seem to be working properly?! How do I sum the constituents and generate a subtotal? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What does not work properly? What output do you get? It will be very helpful if you provide some sample data that represents your issue

Comment: There seem to be a number of syntax errors in the shown SQL code as well; maybe fixing them would solve the issue?

Comment: syntax fixed, thanks.

Comment: I just want to be able to sum  all the c's and all the z's...! so frustrating!